# How can folders be shared to people outside your company with "view only" rights?

Tags: onedrive

When I try to share folders with "view only" rights to people outside our company, OneDrive always warns me that the contacts are outside our company. When I read this warning I share the contents of the folder one-by-one via single file sharing in OneDrive because it presents the "view only" URL sharing option.

Is there a workaround for this disability or am I mistaken about it? Can folders be shared to anyone with "view only" rights same as it's done in single file sharing?